# Sorting an interval

Tags: algorithms, sorting

Given that array has $k$ elements (all distributed uniformly).
Its length is exactly $3$ somewhere in $[0, k)$.

For example, if $k=100$ then, we have $100$ numbers and they can be in $[10,13)$, but they can also be at $[89,92)$

I need to offer a sorting algorithm, which is efficient.

Now, my idea was Bucket Sort, but why would I care the length of the interval is $3$ or $1000$ ? if the numbers are distributed uniformly, then it does not even matter because we could do just a "regular" bucket sort!

But there is a solution that instead of linked lists in each bucket, we use AVL trees. Why would that matter?! the elements still distributed so it is $O(1)$ in each AVL-Tree AND $O(1)$ in each linkedlist...  I really don't get it!

Thanks for helping!

Comment: (It *may* just be a reminder [not to over-engineer solutions](http://c2.com/xp/DoTheSimplestThingThatCouldPossiblyWork.html).)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counting sort: if the first element of the array is $n$, then the values of the array are between $n-2$ and $n+2$. If you count the number of elements equal to each of these 5 values and reorder them, your data are sorted.

This can be done because numbers are in an interval of length 3, so you only have 5 different values to consider given the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any fancy data structures at all,  using counting sort.

Initialize three-element array $C$ to all $0$s and $x$ to infinity. Then loop over every element in $A[i]$ and:

1. Increment $C[A[i] \bmod 3]$.
2. If $A[i] < x$ set $x = A[i]$.

Finally, output an array consisting of $x$ repeated $C[x \bmod 3]$ times, followed by $x + 1$ repeated $C[(x+1)\bmod 3]$ times
and finally $x + 2$ repeated $C[(x+2)\bmod 3]$ times.

Comment: But, why is the solution I wrote, your soution and Nathaniel's are the most optimized? I mean, one of them is the most efficient no? So how would I know how to answer here? In a simple analysis all three seem $O(n)$ which is really the same (both runtime and space I believe)

Comment: (Excruciatingly *data* space conscious;)